Deploying a custom pytorch model on huggingface
I wanted share a Custom Pytorch model based on fine-tuning HuBERT (an audio classification model), also wanted to share with it the custom dataset class cause the processor is working inside the dataset object, i have the state_dict saved on a .pth file and the model/dataset classes.
When i tried to simply make a config files obviously it didn't work, tried to re-train teh model via a Trainer object and push it from there but when i tried to test it with the "use this model" that was created automatically it also didn't work .
My main questions is what's the thing am doing wrong and what should i provide in the repo according to what i wanna accomplish (the trickest part for me is how to share the processor and wetehr should i remover the dataset class and leaver the processor simple as it is and the users should build it they way they want )
Here's the repo that was made by the trainer Here
And here's the model architecture :
class EmotionClassifierHuBERT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(EmotionClassifierHuBERT, self).__init__()
        self.hubert = HubertModel.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1024, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=256, nhead=8)
        self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=256, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=2, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, num_classes)  # * 2 for bidirectional

    def forward(self, x):
        
        with torch.no_grad():
            features = self.hubert(x).last_hidden_state
        features = features.transpose(1, 2)
        
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(features))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = x.transpose(1, 2)
        x = self.transformer_encoder(x)
        x, _ = self.bilstm(x)
        x = self.fc(x[:, -1, :])
        return x

And here's the Dataset class :
class SpeechEmotionDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path, processor=AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")):
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(data_path) if f.endswith('.wav')]
        self.labels = {name: idx for idx, name in enumerate(sorted(set(f.split('_')[2] for f in self.file_list)))}
        self.processor = processor
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        file_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, self.file_list[idx])
        waveform, sr = torchaudio.load(file_path)
        input_values = self.processor(waveform, return_tensors="pt").input_values
        label = self.labels[self.file_list[idx].split('_')[2]]
        return input_values, label
enter code here



